# how to plot how fitted is my data after a MLE?

Tags: r

I have been running a simulation in R by using the maximum likelihood estimation with the following steps:

```
> X<-c(rep(0,14),rep(1,30),rep(2,36),rep(3,68),rep(4,43),rep(5,43),rep(6,30),rep(7,14),rep(8,10),rep(9,6),rep(10,4),rep(11,1),rep(12,1))
> hist(X,right=FALSE,prob=TRUE)
```

so far so good, I generated the data and then plot the histogram; now the MLE part:

```
> negloglike<-function(lam){
+ n*lam-sum(X)*log(lam)+sum(log(factorial(X)))}
> out<-nlm(negloglike,p=c(0.5),hessian=TRUE)
```

after that I obtain the following data:

```
$minimum
[1] 667.183

$estimate
[1] 3.893331

$gradient
[1] -2.575476e-05

$hessian
         [,1]
[1,] 77.03948

$code
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 10
```

for what I have read, the estimate value should be the value of lambda at which my function reaches a maximum, am I right?

The problem is that I would like to draw a line over my histogram plot to see how good is my fitted data. I dont know if I should use abline, curve or other instruction; how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do something like:

```
hist(X, prob=TRUE) 
lambdaEst <- 3.893331
y_seq <- 0:12
lines(y_seq, dpois(y_seq, lambdaEst), col=2, type="b")
```

[image]

As pointed out by Ben it would probably make more sense in this case to use a barplot:

```
plot(table(X)/length(X))
lines(y_seq, dpois(y_seq, lambdaEst), col=2, type="b")
```

[image] 
Another option is then to use `barplot()`:

```
barplot(table(X)/length(X),space=0)
lines(y_seq+1/2, dpois(y_seq, lambdaEst), col=2, type="b")
```

[image]

Comment: `plot(prop.table(table(x)))` (or  `plot(table(x)/length(x))`) might be better

Comment: Yes you are right. Only used `hist()`, because of the way the question was phrased. I will add it.